# Vue on ready or on mounted event of entire app with all components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I was wondering if there is a way to check if the enitre Vue app is mounted?

I am loading a dialog script that checks certain links on the page and add's a dialog event to them.... but the problem is that it runs too early, when the page is loaded. Using jQuery's .ready() function. But at that point not all the components are mounted yet... and some Vue component links are not getting the dialog link events attached.

Something like this I would like to be able to do:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    const app = createApp();
    app.component( 'section-header', SectionHeader );
    // more components etc...

    const mountedApp = app.mount( '#app' );

    if (mountedApp.ready()) {
        // now load my custom non-vue dialog script so we are sure the DOM AND the all components are mounted.
        let CsDialog = require( './vendor/cs-dialog.min' );
        dialog = new CsDialog();
        dialog.bindEvents();
    }
});
```

Comment: I never thought I'd see the day that Vue is mounted within jQuery. Have a look at Lifecycle hooks - https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#beforemount

Comment: Why not use the mounted event in Vue (basically the same thought as above)? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-created-and-mounted-event-in-vuejs/

Comment: Lol. The important part is that the dialog script should be loaded when the entire app is mounted. Not just one component.

Comment: Just using mounted() inside a component isn't enough. Because the dialog script must be loaded after all compontents are mounted.

Comment: Eh, I feel like the approach to this is a bit awkward, rather than listening to a Vue mount/mounted in jQuery, why not just fire the code where you need it in a Vue instance after everything has loaded?

Comment: The problem is, there may not be a single point when all comps are mounted, because they can be mounted and unmounted any time. As for initial mount, parent mount hook runs the last. If it's enough for your case then you can just use mount hook in root component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `jQuery` at all.

The App `mounted()`/`onMounted()` Hooks will be run when all the components are mounted.

See the playground below.

[image]

The App Hooks are being ran at the end.

Check the Vue Docs on [Lifecycle Hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html) and [`onMounted()`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted)

```js
const { createApp, onMounted } = Vue
 
const Comp = {
  props: ['num'],
  setup(props) {
    onMounted(() => { console.log(`Comp[${props.num}]: onMounted(): from setup()`)} );
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(`Comp[${this.num}]:  mounted(): from Options API`)
  }
} 
 
const App = {
  components: {
    Comp
  },
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => { console.log("onMounted(): from setup()")} );
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("mounted(): from Options API")
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<comp v-for="n in 100" :key="n" :num="n"></comp>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: And basically....although you did a very clear job of describing this, this is what was brought up in the intial comments to the question. These [app] hooks are meant for these reasons, to know when you're app is fully mounted...nice example!

Comment: @ViaTech, thanks! A good working example is always helpful and nice to have. That's why I am posting them, even if there is an answer in the comments already.